# Script to upload a file,in selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium-ide

Script to upload a file,in selenium IDE or
How to automate uploading a file using selenium

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
selenium.type("xpath of text box","path of your file")
```

command=type
target=xpath_of_text_box
value=Path_of_your_file

example:

```
selenium.type("id=cvfile", "D:\\Automation\\resume.doc");
```

Comment: This solution is for Selenium WD and not Selenium IDE

Comment: ... and what would you do if the target is missing an `id` but has a class one parent up, but is the second sibling in the HTML code?