# How to attach pictures using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have to include clicking on Browse button and pick a picture from local drive. Can it be done with Selenium IDE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141526/how-do-you-upload-a-file-using-selenium-ide and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718382/script-to-upload-a-file-in-selenium-ide may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the id of File upload section for example (please note that in the solution I am supposing that there is a submit button whose id is Btn_Click on which click the file will get uploaded.)

```
<input type="file" name="abc"  class="input" size="15" id="xyz"/>
```

Then your selenium test case would be like the below

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/Your page where to upload file</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=xyz</td>
    <td>/path of your file to be uploaded</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=btn_click</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```